# Quadratic form as a ratio of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression

I am looking for some hints to prove the following equality:

$y^{\top}y - y^{\top}X(X^{\top}X)^{-1}X^{\top}y = \dfrac{\det(L^{\top}L)}{\det(X^{\top}X)},$

where $y$ is a $n\times 1$ vector, $X$ is a $n\times m$ matrix and $L=(X,y)$ (concatenation of $y$ in the last column of $X$). I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that
$$
\text{det}\left(
\begin{matrix}
  A & B \\
  C & D 
 \end{matrix} 
\right) = \text{det}\left(A\right)\text{det}\left(D-CA^{-1}B\right)
$$

We have that
$$
L^TL = \left(
\begin{matrix}
  X^TX & X^Ty \\
  y^TX & y^Ty
 \end{matrix}
\right).
$$
Thus,
$$
\text{det}\left(L^TL\right) = \text{det}\left(X^TX\right)\text{det}\left(y^Ty-y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty\right).
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{\text{det}\left(L^TL\right) }{\text{det}\left(X^TX\right) }& = \text{det}\left(y^Ty-y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty\right)\\& = y^Ty-y^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
\end{align}
where the last equality follows from that fact that $\text{det}\left(c\right)=c$ for $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I will accept the answer if you provide another hint on how to decompose $L$. Thanks.

Comment: @MaxPower See edit.

Comment: Many thanks ...

Comment: You're welcome :-)